# findViewByIdlayoutinflator fails to inflate my layouts, returns null when using

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

my main activity calls for view to inflate my main.xml but whatever reason always seems to return null,  i'm kind of lost here since this worked in 4.2 but now doesn't after upgrading the rest of my source to 6.0

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

    setContentView(layout);

    ctx = this;

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    res = getResources();

    mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    mMediaButtonReceiver = new RemoteControlReceiver();
    mediaFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    mediaFilter.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    registerReceiver(mMediaButtonReceiver, mediaFilter);

    //mDrawable = (this.res.getDrawable(R.drawable.glowy_metal));
    //mBackground.setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
    mBackground = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.background);
    mBackground.setOnTouchListener(new backgroundTouchListener());
```

logcat shows null here:

```
mBackground = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.background);
```

the background id in my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/glowy_metal"/>
```

can anyone shed some insight as to what might be going on here?

logcat :

```
D/AndroidRuntime(12906): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(12906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12906): Process: com.cphelps76.CarHome, PID: 12906
E/AndroidRuntime(12906): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cphelps76.CarHome/com.cphelps76.CarHome.CarHomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnTouchListener(android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnTouchListener(android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at com.cphelps76.CarHome.CarHomeActivity.onCreate(CarHomeActivity.java:211)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
E/AndroidRuntime(12906):    ... 10 more
W/ActivityManager(  789):   Force finishing activity 1 com.cphelps76.CarHome/.CarHomeActivity
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and then later

```
mBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background);
```

No need to create a new inflater since the `Activity` already has methods to do what you want.

Comment: that's how i originally had it but it still gave me null and crashed the app when opening it. logcat shows null at mBackground = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.background); regardless how i've set it

Comment: Update your question and include the output of the crash so we can help see what went wrong.

Comment: Is that after updating the code with what I have here? It shouldn't really matter but notice that `findViewById(..)` is not using the `layout` view.

Comment: You don't have a custom version of that layout depending on API level do you? Try casting layout to a `RelativeLayout` and call `getChildCount()` on it to see if it has one child. Or call `((RelativeLayout) layout).getChildAt(0)` to see if it is your ImageView

Comment: @cphelps76 Did you ever find out what the issue was here?

Comment: After walking away and leaving it alone for a little while I finally figured out what was going on.  Awhile back I had included my lib package in the build of the app itself and it never crossed my mind to check the name of my lib layout resource against the app layout resources.  I had layouts with the same name and the lib layout was being inflated instead of the app layout so everything was null and non exiatent